# Clojure data.xml error

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, clojure, xmlstreamreader

I have a leiningen project with [org.clojure/data.xml "0.0.7"] as a dependency and an xml file in  data/data-sample.xml

**That works:**

```
(require '[clojure.xml :as xml])
(xml/parse "data/small-sample.xml")
```

**It returns:**

```
{:tag :data, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :person, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :given-name, :attrs nil, :content ["Gomez"]} {:tag :surname, :attrs nil, :content ["Addams"]} {:tag :relation, :attrs nil, :content ["father"]}]} {:tag :person, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :given-name, :attrs nil, :content ["Morticia"]}...
```

**That doesn't work:**

```
(require '[clojure.data.xml :as data.xml])
(data.xml/parse "data/small-sample.xml")
```

**It returns:**

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: createXMLStreamReader for class com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in its docstring, `clojure.data.xml/parse` accepts an `InputStream` or `Reader`, so that's what you need to provide:

```
(require '[clojure.data.xml :as xml]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(xml/parse (io/reader "data/small-sample.xml"))
```

Note that `io/reader` attempts to treat strings as URIs as a first guess, then as local file names. You can use `io/file` if you want to be explicit about dealing with a file (`(io/reader (io/file ...))`). There's also `io/resource` for looking things up on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow, I expected them to behave the same way. I opened a new issue that I am having as a follow up to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094278/clojure-leining-repl-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Comment: I wonder though, how does the error message come to explain the problem?